# How to reset nested navigators (react-navigation v5)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

Having two sets of stack navigators;

```
const SetOneScreens = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="AScreen">
    <Stack.Screen name="AScreen" component={AScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="BScreen" component={BScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
const SetTwoScreens = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="CScreen">
    <Stack.Screen name="CScreen" component={CScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="DScreen" component={DScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Which are nested in a Drawer navigator

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="SetOneScreens">
        <Drawer.Screen name="SetOneScreens" component={SetOneScreens} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="SetTwoScreens" component={SetTwoScreens} options={{swipeEnabled: false}} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

I want to navigate From `BScreen` to `DScreen` and reset the stack (in order to not letting hardware back button in android get back to `BScreen`)

As in the nesting situation, we should first define the navigator name; how should I define the screen in reset action.

```
// For navigation 
props.navigation.navigate('setTwoScreens',{screen:'DScreen'})

// For reset I can only navigate to initial screen 
props.navigation.reset({index:0,routes:[{name:'setTwoScreens'}]})
```

How should I handle the `reset` with `navigation` or `CommonActions`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset) of react-navigation-v5, you need to dispatch CommonAction with reset-action to clear back-stack of your application, so that application doesn't go back to previous screen when user press hardware back-button of device, check below example,

```
import { CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

props.navigation.dispatch({
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ name: "AnotherStackNavigator" }]
  })
});
```

Or if you want to reset to specific screen in that StackNavigator you can do like this:

```
props.navigation.dispatch({
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        name: "AnotherStackNavigator",
        state: {
          routes: [
            {
              name: "AnotherStackNavigatorScreen",
              params: {         
                  ...
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
});
```

Comment: with this solution I am facing one problem. I am able to navigate to different stack at specified depth but the back button won't go to the root of the new stack. how to fix this?

Comment: @WaheedAkhter this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71835841/4490052

Answer (score 10):

I tried the solution from Aditya, but had issues with the back button not going back to the root of the new stack.

This seemed to fix that issue for me though:

```
props.navigation.dispatch({
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        name: "AnotherStackNavigator",
        state: {
          routes: [
            {
              name: "AnotherStackNavigatorRootScreen"
            },
            {
              name: "AnotherStackNavigatorScreen",
              params: {         
                  ...
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
});
```