# How do navigate to a tab from another tab using react navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have 3 tabs and each tab contains a set of stack navigators.

1. Home Stack

```js
const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStackNavigator = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    return (
        <HomeNavigator.Navigator>
            <HomeNavigator.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={Home}
            />
            <HomeNavigator.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={Profile}
            />
            <HomeNavigator.Screen
                name="Settings"
                component={Settings}
            />
        </HomeNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};
```

2. Store Stack

```js
const StoreNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const StoreStackNavigator = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    return (
        <StoreNavigator.Navigator>
            <StoreNavigator.Screen
                name="OurStore"
                component={Store}
            />
        </StoreNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};
```

3. Community Stack

```js
const CommunityNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const CommunityStackNavigator = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    return (
        <CommunityNavigator.Navigator>
            <CommunityNavigator.Screen
                name="Community"
                component={Community}
            />
            <CommunityNavigator.Screen
                name="CommunityReply"
                component={CommunityReply}
                options={communityReplyOptions}
            />
            <CommunityNavigator.Screen
                name="AskCommunity"
                component={AskCommunity}
            />
        </CommunityNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Tab Navigator

```js
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MainTabNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MainNavigator.Navigator
            screenOptions={tabScreenOptions}
            tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}
        >
            <MainNavigator.Screen
                name="HomeTab"
                component={HomeStackNavigator}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: "Home" }}
            />
            <MainNavigator.Screen
                name="StoreTab"
                component={StoreStackNavigator}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: "Store" }}
            />
            <MainNavigator.Screen
                name="CommunityTab"
                component={CommunityStackNavigator}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: "Community" }}
            />
        </MainNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};
```

*Now Home tab when a button clicked I need to navigate to CommunityReply Screen inside Community Tab Navigator. Can some please help me with this*

**Package versions**

- @react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0
- @react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3
- @react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The below should work in this case:

```js
navigation.navigate('CommunityTab', { screen: 'CommunityReply' });
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it with navigation.reset? I was doing it like this, but it didn't work.
this.props.navigation.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [{name: 'CommunityTab', screen: 'CommunityReply'}],
              })

Comment: try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63528641/7022711

Comment: And if you need send params to screen use `navigation.navigate('CommunityTab', { screen: 'CommunityReply',  params: {key: 'value'}});`

Answer (score 0):

can use this:

```
const jumpToAction = TabActions.jumpTo('CommunityReply'); 
navigation.dispatch(jumpToAction);
navigation.navigate('CommunityTab');
```